# Laravel 5.3 Ajax show view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with Ajax. I have a controller where is get response from external API. In this controller are passing variables to API request. The result is passing to a view. 
On this view I have drop down list with currency's. I want when user select another currency the new request will be send to API and generate new view.

Below is file and code.

web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@nbp');
Route::post('/home','HomeController@nbp');
```

HomeController.php

```
    public function nbp(Request $request)
        {
                $data = $request->all();


            if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){

                $data = response()->json($data);
                $data = $data->getContent();
                $data = json_decode($data, true);
                $currency = $data['currency'];
                Debugbar::info($currency);

            }else{
                $currency = 'EUR';
            }

             $tabeA = 'a';

 // Create a client with a base URI
                $client = new GuzzleHttpClient(['base_uri' => 'http://api.nbp.pl/api/'],['headers'=>['content-type'=> 'application/json']]);



                // Send a request
                $response = $client->request('GET', 'exchangerates/rates/'.$tableA.'/'.$currency);

                 $response->getStatusCode();
                // 200
                //$contentType = $response->getReasonPhrase();
                // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
                $currency =  json_decode($response->getBody());

                $data = $currency->rates;
                $data2 = $data[0]->mid;

       if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
             return view('home',compact('currency'))->render();
            }else{
    return view('home',compact('currency'));
            }

                }
```

script.js

```
$('#currencyNameA').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     url: '/home',
      data:  { currency : $('#currencyNameA').val()},
   success: function(data){


   },
   complete: function(data){


   }
  });
});
```

The request to API must be http://api.nbp.pl/api/$table/$currency

Example:
http://api.nbp.pl/api/a/USD

Comment: can you provide the view and the javascript code?

Comment: where do you display the result that comes from the api?

Comment: return view('home',compact('currency'));

Comment: i mean html not the php code, the page template

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Return json from your controller if you do a ajax call:

```
$currency =  json_decode($response->getBody());

                $data = $currency->rates;
                $data2 = $data[0]->mid;

       if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
             return response()->json(["currency"=>$currency]);
            }else{
    return view('home',compact('currency'));
            }
```

in the success function output the data to the page

```
 success: function(data){
    $('body').append(data.currency.rates[0].mid);//change the body element with your element
   },
```

Comment: The request to API must be http://api.nbp.pl/api/$table/$currency

Example:
http://api.nbp.pl/api/a/USD

Comment: from what i can see you are doing the request via php

Comment: I need pass API response to a controller because I need do some math on this response before pass result to a view.

Comment: then do with with the custom route

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

VIEW

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Currency</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/currency','method' =>'post')) !!}
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <select name="currency" id="currencyNameA">
                            @foreach($currency_table_A->rates as $rows)
                                <option value="{{ $rows->code }}">{{ $rows->currency }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    <br />
                    <h2>
                        <div class="currency" id="ajax_currency">currency {{$currency->currency}} {{ $currency->rates[0]->mid}} last update was {{ $currency->rates[0]->effectiveDate }}</div>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Controller

```
public function nbp(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
        $cur = $request->input('currency'); //get currency from post
        //Debugbar::info($cur);
    }else{
        $cur = 'EUR';
    }
    $tabeA = 'a';

    // Create a client with a base URI
    $client = new GuzzleHttpClient(['base_uri' => 'http://api.nbp.pl/api/'],['headers'=>['content-type'=> 'application/json']]);
    // Send a request
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'exchangerates/rates/'.$tableA.'/'.$cur);

    $response->getStatusCode();
    // 200
    //$contentType = $response->getReasonPhrase();
    // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    $currency =  json_decode($response->getBody());

    $data = $currency->rates;
    $data2 = $data[0]->mid;

    if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
        return response()->json(['currency' => $data, 'mid' => $data2, 'updated' => $currency->rates[0]->effectiveDate]);
    }else{
        return view('home', compact('currency'));
    }
}
```

JS

```
$('#currencyNameA').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    url: '/home',
    data:  { currency : $('#currencyNameA').val()},
    success: function(data){
        $('#ajax_currency').html('currency '+data.currency+' '+data.mid+' last update was '+data.updated);
    },
    complete: function(data){
      //ajax complete
    }
  });
});
```

When user loads the page (not Ajax) a view will render with all ur data that u `compact`

When user triggers the select change a ajax call will be made and you will recieve a json data `(array)` and this data you will fill inside `div` called `ajax_currency` (where you echo your data from normal page visit) hope it is clean now.

This way you dont rerender a view you just change a piece of it via JS.

Answer (score 0):

OK maybe one more time because we probable misunderstand.

I have a view:

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Currency</div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/currency','method' =>'post')) !!}
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <select name="currency" id="currencyNameA">
                 @foreach($currency_table_A->rates as $rows)

                 <option value="{{ $rows->code }}">{{ $rows->currency }}</option>

                @endforeach
                </select>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

                    <br />

                <h2><div class="currency">
                currency {{$currency->currency}} {{ $currency->rates[0]->mid}} last update was {{ $currency->rates[0]->effectiveDate }}
                </div>
                </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And a controller:

```
 public function getCurrency(Request $request)
     {       

          $client = new GuzzleHttpClient(['base_uri' => 'http://api.nbp.pl/api/'],['headers'=>['content-type'=>
 'application/json']]);

             //Table for dropdown list Begin
             $table_response = $client->request('GET','exchangerates/tables/a');
             $currency_table_A =  json_decode($table_response->getBody());
             $currency_table_A = $currency_table_A[0];
             //Table for dropdown list End

         if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
             $cur = $request->input('currency'); //get currency from post
         }else{
             $cur = 'EUR';
         }  

     // Send a request to External API
     $response = $client->request('GET', 'exchangerates/rates/a/'.$cur);

     //Antwser from External API
     $currency =  json_decode($response->getBody());


   if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
        //In Debug bar i get reply form API but my View is not change
        Debugbar::info($currency);
        return response()->json(view('curentCurrency', compact('currency','currency_table_A'))->render());
    }else{
        return view('curentCurrency', compact('currency','currency_table_A'));
    }
    }
```

Script.js

```
$('#currencyNameA').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     url: '/currency',
      data:  { currency : $('#currencyNameA').val()},
   success: function(data){  
   }
  });
});
```

I need to pass a new answer to a View when was select new currency in drop list. When page is loaded first time i need to get basic value in USD when someone change from drop down list the currency result should change for that user choose.

Comment: Updated my answer